# Tuplas en Python

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente tupla mostrada de distintos tipos de datos (str, int y float), para ello requiero elaborar un programa para recorrerla y crear tres listas en las que se guarden esos tipos de datos, es decir una lista para los datos de tipo int, una lista para los datos de tipo float y una lista para los datos de tipo str, e imprimir cada una una de las listas con sus respectivos tipos de datos por separado, así:

```
Tupla = (1, 2, "Hola", 3.3, "hello", 5, 4.3)
```

Tengo el siguiente código, pero no me da

```
tupla = (1, 2, "Hola", 3.3, "hello", 5, 4.3)
print(tupla)   
print(tupla[0])
print(tupla[1])
print(tupla[2])
print(tupla.int[1, 2, 5])
print(tupla.float(3.3, 4.3)
Print (tupla.str(Hola, hello)
```

Comment: difiero si es funcional o bajo-nivel

Comment: yo te recomiendo que tomes un curso de python estas son preguntas demaciado basicas que no requieren conocimiento avanzado solo conocer de bucles y logica de programacion por lo que no requiere depuracion requieres es hacerte la tarea!

Answer (score 0):

```
intV=[]
strV=[]
floatV=[]

tupla = (1, 2, "Hola", 3.3, "hello", 5, 4.3)
for i in tupla:
    if isinstance(i, int) == True:
        intV.append(i)
    if isinstance(i, str) == True:
        strV.append(i)
    if isinstance(i, float) == True:
        floatV.append(i)

print(tupla)

print(intV)
print(strV)
print(floatV)
```

te invito a revisar el codigo bien realiza lo que pides ademas te recomiendo revisar la funcion "isinstance" que te permite conparar el tipo del dato

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Aqui otra solucion sin el uso de `isinstance` y que crea las listas dinamicamente segun los tipos de datos (es decir, se crean tantas listas como tipos de datos pongas en tu tupla):

```
tupla = (1, 2, "Hola", 3.3, "hello", 5, 4.3)

tipos = list(set(type(x) for x in tupla))
result = [[] for i in tipos]
for item in tupla:
    ind = tipos.index(type(item))
    result[ind].append(item)
for item in range(len(tipos)):
    print(f'\t{tipos[item]}\t')
    print(*result[item], sep=', ', end='\n')
```

este es mi output

```
> python tuplas-en-python.py
        <class 'int'>
1, 2, 5
        <class 'str'>
Hola, hello
        <class 'float'>
3.3, 4.3
```

Primero inicializamos la variable `tupla` con la lista de elementos que gustes. Luego, la variable `tipos` es una lista que se genera al aplicar la funcion `set` a un iterador sobre los elementos de `tupla` y mirará los resultados de   `type(x)` donde `x` es un elemento de `tupla`, de esta manera solo conservará los valores únicos de los tipos de `tupla`.

Una vez que tenemos guardados los valores unicos de los tipos, procedemos a crear una lista vacia que contiene tantas listas como tipos distintos de datos hay en tupla. Para crearla he usado la comprension de listas.

Luego, dentro del primer bucle `for`, recorremos una sola vez cada elemento de tupla a traves de la variable `item`, luego nos preguntamos cual es el tipo de dato de `item` y le preguntamos a la lista `tipos` por el indice de este tipo de dato. Conocido el indice, solo hacemos `append` a la lista que almacena los elementos de `tupla` que corresponden a ese tipo de dato.

Debes notar, que `tipos` y `result` mantienen cierto orden, por ejemplo el primer elemento de `tipos` es para `int`, y de manera correspondiente la primera lista de `result` solo guardará elementos del tipo `int`.

Debes notar tambien que solo hacemos un unico bucle y nos ahorramos el uso de condicionales como `if` y de recorrer enteramente `tupla` por cada elemento de `tipos`.

El ultimo print solo es para dar formato, desempaquetamos `result[items]` con un `*` al inicio e indicamos el separador con `sep`.